# Output in cli from PHP is always in one line (using PHP_EOL)

Tags: php, newline

I have a script to determine if there are Wordpress updates. I use this on 2 Debian 11 lxc containers. In one container it works as expected, I get 3 lines of output under each other.
In the othe one, I got only one line, like this:

```
root@container2:/usr/lib/check_mk_agent/local# php -f check_wordpress.php 
0 "Wordpress version" - Wordpress version 6.2.2 is up-to-date P "Wordpress plugins" pending_updates=0;1;3;; All Wordpress plugins up-to-date P "Wordpress themes" pending_updates=0;1;;; All Wordpress themes up-to-dateroot@container2:/usr/lib/check_mk_agent/local#
```

I expect to get this:

```
root@container2:/usr/lib/check_mk_agent/local# php -f check_wordpress.php 
0 "Wordpress version" - Wordpress version 6.2.2 is up-to-date
P "Wordpress plugins" pending_updates=0;1;3;; All Wordpress plugins up-to-date
P "Wordpress themes" pending_updates=0;1;;; All Wordpress themes up-to-date
root@container2:/usr/lib/check_mk_agent/local#
```

Here is the script (sorry, I'm not a PHP pro):

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$path = '/var/www';
$update_core = false;
$update_plugins = array();
$update_themes = array();

require_once("$path/wp-load.php");

global $wp_version;

wp_update_plugins();
wp_version_check();
wp_update_themes();

$core = get_site_transient('update_core');
$plugins = get_site_transient('update_plugins');
$themes = get_site_transient('update_themes');

if ($themes) {
    foreach($themes->response as $theme) {
        array_push($update_themes, $theme['theme']);
    }
}
if ($plugins) {
    foreach($plugins->response as $plugin) {
        array_push($update_plugins, $plugin->slug);
    }
}
if ($core) {
    $arr_core = $core->updates;
    if (is_array($arr_core) && $arr_core[0]) {
        $obj_core = $arr_core[0];
        if ($obj_core->response && $obj_core->response != "latest") {
            $update_core = $obj_core->current;
        }
    }
}

if ($update_core) {
    $installed_version_array = explode(".". $wp_version);
    $available_version_array = explode(".". $update_core);
    if ($available_version_array[0] > $installed_version_array[0] || $available_version_array[1] > $installed_version_array[1]) {
        print "2 \"Wordpress version\" - Wordpress version upgrade from $wp_version to $update_core". PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        print "1 \"Wordpress version\" - Wordpress version upgrade from $wp_version to $update_core". PHP_EOL;
    }
} else {
    print "0 \"Wordpress version\" - Wordpress version $wp_version is up-to-date". PHP_EOL;
}

$pending_plugins = sizeof($update_plugins);
if ($update_plugins) {
    $msg_plugins = "$pending_updates Wordpress plugins outdated (". join($update_plugins, ", "). ")";
} else {
    $msg_plugins = "All Wordpress plugins up-to-date";
}
print "P \"Wordpress plugins\" pending_updates=$pending_plugins;1;3;; $msg_plugins". PHP_EOL;

$pending_themes = sizeof($update_themes);
if ($update_themes) {
    $msg_themes = "$pending_themes Wordpress themes outdated (". join($update_themes, ", "). ")";
} else {
    $msg_themes = "All Wordpress themes up-to-date";
}
print "P \"Wordpress themes\" pending_updates=$pending_themes;1;;; $msg_themes". PHP_EOL;

?>
```

As far as I know, PHP_EOL is the best for new line chars in PHP. I don't get it, why I get only one line.

First try was to use "\n", that works on conainer 1 like a charm, then I switched to PHP_EOL.
I compare the php.ini and installed modules, all are the same.
Also I tried echo instead of print.

Comment: You can try echo instead of print.

Comment: Thanks @WolfgangBlessen, as I wrote, I already tried this, does not change anything.

Comment: What are the differences in the containers?